# Windows phone 7 and windows phone 8 differences

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Can anybody provide me the link or blog-post for kernel level and core features differences  between windows phone 7 and windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a developers point of view? :[Nokia has a guide for side by side development highlighting the differences](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Co-development_for_Windows_Phone_7/8_and_Windows_8_guide)

Comment: Not kernel level though

Answer (score 1):

You can see difference between Windows phone 7 and Windows phone 8 [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/whats-new-in-windows-phone).

Don't forget you've acces to the update system information [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history) with new features by updates...

But all windows phone devices have not already the last version of the system.

Also, a new "Big Update" named "GDR2" ( it's the windows phone 8.1 version)  is actually in progress for the windows phone 8... lot of websites list all new features for this update. [here for sample](http://www.wpcentral.com/tag/gdr2).

Comment: GDR2 is not a big update, it's actually a small one. GDR3 is due later in the year. Windows Phone 8.1 (or Blue) is due early next year.